# RxSwift best practice: Shall I use a Subject for my internal data source?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am still fairly new to the Rx world and I was wondering if I am doing it right or if I have a misconception and are violating the best practices. If so, I'd be happy if you could point me to the right direction.

In my iOS app I need to call a web service to retrieve my data. There are basically two calls I can make:

- A call to a collection resource (/devices)
- A call to a single resource (/devices/{id})

To reduce the amount of calls I need to do I thought it would be a good idea to store the data locally in memory so that when I go from the list view (which displays all devices) to the detail view (which displays a single device), I don't have to make a call to the single resource.

Instead, I would only make this call when the user uses pull to refresh inside the detail screen and then write back the data to the collection which is used as the datasource for the list screen.

Now due to the fact that the app is running on a mobile device, there can be multiple errors while making a call to the web service and if an error occurs I would like to show a message to the user to inform about the problem.

I was thinking about using a Subject inside a Singleton class as my data source to which my UI subscribes. Whenever I need to refresh the list, I would create a new observable with my web service call which, as a side effect, populates new data to the Subject but does not populate onError or onComplete events to the Subject.

I hope this piece of pseudo code explains better what I mean:

```
//Pull-to-refresh function
Observable.create { observable in
  let hud = HUD("loading devices")
  self.hud = hud
  observable.next()
  return Disposable.create { hud.dismiss() }
}
.flatMap {
  return DeviceService.getList() //The web service
}
.flatMap { devices in
  DeviceSingleton.devicesSubject.next(devices) //The singleton
  return Observable.just()
}
.subscribe(
  onNext: { self.hud.dismiss() }
  onError: { error in 
      self.hud.dismiss()
      self.displayError(error)
  }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The pull-to-refresh in the detail screen would look similar but it would involve getting the current data from the subject, then replacing the updated device and re-publishing the data like so:

```
//Pull-to-refresh function in detail screen
let id = ...
Observable.create { observable in
  let hud = HUD("loading devices")
  self.hud = hud
  observable.next()
  return Disposable.create { hud.dismiss() }
}
.flatMap {
  return DeviceService.getDevice(id: id) //The web service
}
.flatMap { device in
  let devices = try! DeviceSingleton.devicesSubject.value()
  let updatedDevices = self.updateDevice(device, in: devices) //removing old device, adding new one, sorting, etc.
  DeviceSingleton.devicesSubject.next(devices) 
  return Observable.just()
}
.subscribe(
  onNext: { self.hud.dismiss() }
  onError: { error in 
      self.hud.dismiss()
      self.displayError(error)
  }
)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Is this correct? Is this valid? What could be a better approach? I think one problem might be that reloading a single device can not only happen when the user pulls-to-refresh but also when a remote notification comes in.

I hope you can tell me if I am using Rx correctly or if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at *.materialize()* and *.switchLatest()* operators, they come in handy in such scenarios.

I personally prefer to keep latest state by using this small library - https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift